# Find the degree of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11},\sqrt[3]{11}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

I am trying to find the degree of the following field extension:

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11},\sqrt[3]{11}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11})$.

I know it must be at most three since $\sqrt[3]{11}$ is a root of $x^3-11$. I have also proven that it cant be 1 because if it was, that would mean there would exist two rational numbers a and b such that $11=(a+ b\sqrt{11})^3$ which is not true for any rational a,b. I assume that I then have to prove it can not be two either, which leaves me with the answer, 3. How can I prove it is not 2?

Comment: You are right. What I meant to say was that it must be at most 3. I just edited it.

Comment: Do you know the relationship between the three numbers $$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11},\sqrt[3]{11}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11})]\\
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11}):\mathbb{Q}]\\
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11},\sqrt[3]{11}):\mathbb{Q}]$$?

Comment: To be completely honest I am not aware of the relationship between them. I know the second one has degree 1, and the third has degree 3 but I don't know much about the first.

Comment: What Arthur means is the [degree theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Degree_of_Field_Extensions_is_Multiplicative), which is very basic for dealing with field extensions. It is no surprise that the answer below is using it.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Yes, using the tower law, I know that If A, B, C are fields and A ⊆ B ⊆ C, then,
[C : A] = [C : B][B : A]. I am new to Galois theory, so I am just trying to read new books and understand further.

Comment: In this case you have proved that the cubic polynomial $x^3-11\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11})[x]$ has no roots in $F=\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{11})$ and this implies that $x^3-11$ is irreducible over $F$ and hence $F(\sqrt[3]{11})$ is of degree $3$ over $F$. The degree law or tower theorem allows you to conclude the same without any analysis of roots.

Answer (score 2):

Write $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{11}$ and $\beta = \sqrt{11}$. Then you have the following inclusions of fields, namely
$\mathbb Q \subseteq \mathbb Q(\alpha) \subseteq \mathbb Q(\alpha, \beta)$ and
$\mathbb Q \subseteq \mathbb Q(\beta) \subseteq \mathbb Q(\alpha, \beta)$.

Using the tower formula, you know that $[\mathbb Q(\alpha, \beta) : \mathbb Q] = [\mathbb Q(\alpha, \beta) : \mathbb Q(\alpha)] \cdot [\mathbb Q(\alpha) : \mathbb Q] $ and similarly for $\beta$. As you know that $\mathbb Q(\alpha) : \mathbb Q= 3$, we find that $3$ divides $[\mathbb Q(\alpha, \beta) : \mathbb Q]$ and hence also $[\mathbb Q(\alpha, \beta) : \mathbb Q(\beta)]$. Along with the fact that $[\mathbb Q(\alpha, \beta) : \mathbb Q(\beta)]\leq 3$ this suffices.

Comment: That really helps! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! In fact, this method usually works for most excercises of this type. You do not need that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both roots of $11$, only that the degrees of $\alpha$ and $\beta$  over $\mathbb Q$ are co-prime.  

Also, consider accepting this answer to mark this question as closed.

Answer (score -1):

Notice that $x^3-11$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11})$.
It's obvious that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{11}, \sqrt{11}): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11})]=3$.